# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. While Running Flutter build apk

Tags: flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies, flutter-build

While run Flutter build apk getting thia error....[Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbPG2.png)

[This is my build.gradle...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR21g.png)

[App level gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4yVf.png)

[App level gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHoDN.png)

I try run flutter clean and flutter build apk...
I add latest kotlin version , nothing work for me..

Comment: I can run Flutter run it work properly but i run flutter build apk its getiing error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.